How to show that a subset of a normed space isn't dense?
Consider an arbitrary normed vector space $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_X)$  and let $Y \subset X$. We say that $Y$ is dense in $X$ if and only if
$$ \forall x \in X, \epsilon > 0, \, \exists y \in Y : \Vert y - x \Vert_X < \epsilon. $$
Now, my question is pretty simple:

When we want to prove that $Y$ isn't dense in $X$, what exactly do we
have to show ?

My thoughts. I believe that I was able to provide a condition that answers my question, but I would like to know if there are any weaker conditions that lead me to the same outcome.
So, my idea is as follows. To show that $Y$ isn't dense in $X$, I believe that it is sufficient to find an element $x_0 \in X$ such that there exists a constant $c > 0$ satisfying
$$ \Vert x_0 - y \Vert_X \geqslant c > 0, $$
for every $y \in Y$.
Now, when I mentioned a weaker condition, I was thinking about the following:
If we find an element $x_0 \in X$ such that for every $y \in Y$ there exists a constant $c(y) > 0$ satisfying
$$ \| x_0 - y \|_X \geqslant c(y) > 0, $$
does it also follow that $Y$ isn't dense in $X$ ?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Your weaker condition is actually equivalent to $Y \neq X$.  It's far too weak.

@BrianMoehring Thanks for your comment. I suspected that this would be the case.

One pair of sufficient conditions would be: $Y$ is closed and $Y\neq X$. A necessary and sufficient condition is: $X\setminus Y$ has a non-empty interior.

Your weaker condition cannot work, for it would be satisfied by any sequence $\{y_n\}$ that converges to $x_0$. That is, the condition is satisfied by any dense subspace.
Here are some equivalent conditions, given a subspace $Y\subset X$:

$Y$ is not dense in $X$;

there exists $x_0\in X\setminus \overline Y$;

there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(x_0,Y)>0$;

there exists $x_0\in X$ and $f\in X^*$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f|_Y=0$;

there exists $c\in\mathbb R$, $x_0\in X$ and $f\in X^*$ with
$$
\operatorname{Re}f(x_0)<c<\operatorname{Re}f(y),\qquad\qquad y\in Y. 
$$



Just to be clear, the standard way to show that a certain property doesn't hold is to prove that the negation of it is true. So in this case, what you would need to prove is the negation of the definition that OP gave: $\exists x\in X, \varepsilon >0, \forall y\in Y : ||x-y||_X\geq \varepsilon$. This is a mathematical way of saying that you can find a point in $X$ which cannot be approximated arbitrarily well from $Y$. Another way to phrase the same thing is the third bullet point from the answer above.

That is a very good description @Leon . I hope future readers come across your comment.
